# Angular ngx-datatable not refreshing

Tags: angular, angular6, ngx-datatable

I have tried below code, everything seems okay(not getting any error and even data is there from api call) but at last I am getting an empty table.

`*reloadTable*` is the function which calls the API.

**Data from API call :**
[image]

**Empty table :**
[image]

```
@Component({
      selector: 'app-my-component',
      template: `
        <ngx-datatable
          class="bootstrap table table-striped"
          [rows]="rows"
          [columns]="columns"
          [columnMode]="'force'"
          [headerHeight]="50"
          [footerHeight]="50"
          [rowHeight]="'auto'"
          [externalPaging]="true"
          [externalSorting]="true"
          [count]="page.count"
          [offset]="page.offset"
          [limit]="page.limit"
          [sortType]="'single'"
          (page)="pageCallback($event)"
          (sort)="sortCallback($event)"
        ></ngx-datatable>
      `
    })

    export class NGXServerSide implements OnInit {
      rows: Object[]=[];      
      columns = [
        { name: 'EmployeeID' },
        { name: 'Name' },
        { name: 'City' },
        { name: 'Department' },
        { name: 'Gender' },
      ];         
      constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private _employeeService: EmployeeService) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.pageCallback({ offset: 1 });
      }
    pageCallback(pageInfo: { count?: number, pageSize?: number, limit?: number, offset?: number }) {
        this.page.offset = pageInfo.offset;
        this.reloadTable();
      }        
    reloadTable() {
    const params = this.addTableParams();// params for api input
    this._employeeService.getSortedPagedResults(params).subscribe((res: Response) => {
     for (var i in res)       
     this.rows.push([res[i]]);
     this.page.count=1;
     });
     }  
    }
```

Comment: The actual problem statement or question is missing...

Comment: m not getting @LaurenzAlbe..

Comment: Well, I'm not getting it either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking over your question more, I see what the issue is. You're passing data to the datatable but it is not being displayed. There are two problems:

1. The datatable doesn't know what to bind to. In the NGXServerSide class, you're only giving the column a name. Give the column a property to bind like so:

   `columns = [{ name: 'EmployeeID', prop: 'EmployeeID' }]`
2. The object you're passing in doesn't match the column name. In the screenshot I can see `EmployeeId: '1'`, but your column is expecting `EmployeeID`

I'm including a link below from the ngx-datatable API documentation that contains some additional column properties you can use.
[ngx-datatable column properties](https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-datatable/api/column/inputs)

Comment: Thanks @emmojo, its working now.   { name: 'EmployeeId', prop: 'EmployeeId' } did the trick. Actually i had already changed it from 'EmployeeID' to 'EmployeeId' but the prop is the main reason to make it work..

Comment: can u pl check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50982494/how-to-reorder-ngx-datatables-column-in-angular

Comment: Sure, I'll take a look.